# How do I get the last RTD update time in Excel?

Tags: excel, rtd

I am using the `RTD` Excel function to subscribe to topics of a ProgID like this:

```
=RTD("tos.rtd",,"LAST","SPY")
```

If I have a number of cells with different topics from that ProgID, how can I determine the last time each was updated, *even if the value did not change*?